# Exception while passing JSON string(multiple parameters) to method in WebAPI service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

While trying to pass a JSON data from script side to the method inside WebAPI service we are getting the following exception.

```
{
  "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '.../api/Values/Sample'.",
  "MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Values'."
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:

While using WebAPI in .net 4.0 and VS2010 we didn’t experience any such issue but when we use WebAPI in .net 4.5 and VS2012 we saw the issue. So kindly diagnosis this with 4.5 framework.
 We have attached the sample in the following link. If you could review and post the correct sample with comments it would be really helpful as we are new to WebAPI concepts. Event posting code snippet with proper comments would be fine.

SAMPLE LINK: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gb197faeca5017d489993001280c7f122f64fc06a7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your sample. Couple of things to fix it:

1.Change the controller name from `ValuesController1` to `ValuesController`. Web API by default looks for controller classes with suffix 'Controller'.

2.Change your route to the following:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, 

Thanks for the suggestions. I made changes in both the files and while running the project, irrelevant method (Post() method called instead of Sample() method) has been called by script.
Could you please suggest the way to call the specific method (Sample)?

Thanks again.

Comment: Your "Sample" action method looks like "Sample(string Position, string Others, string Info)"...so your POST request url should look like `/api/Values?position=something&others=something&info=something`...the idea here is that there are 2 post methods in your controller and you are overloading(like C# method overloading) these actions by using query string parameters...